# Polynomial irreducible $\implies $ "Reverse" polynomial irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

> If $$a_nx^n+\cdots +a_0$$ is irreducible over some field, the polynomial $$a_0x^n+\cdots +a_n$$ with the coefficients reversed is irreducible over the same field as well.

Suppose the polynomial can be expressed as product of two polynomial the original polynomial will be reduced. Thats what I want to do but I ran out of idea. can someone help me?

Comment: Hint:  if $p(x)$ is the given polynomial, then the "reverse" polynomial is given by $x^np\left( \frac 1x\right)$.

Comment: @lulu: I think you can make this an answer.

Comment: Can u explain further?